# Load balancing an image stored on Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm investingating using Amazon S3 for a project, and had a question about how it handles load balancing. Can I assume that an image uploaded to S3 is store on a single hard drive in one place, and the load balancing needs to be handled in the application layer? What are viable solutions for handling image load balancing for images stored on S3? Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about Operating System Images, or Images.jpg. You don't worry about Load Balancing for S3. That's Amazon's job and that is what you pay them for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that S3 will take care of all of that for you.  You just set up your account, throw the data into the proper buckets, and Amazon does the rest. The only load balancing you need to worry about is the instances that you are running.

Answer (score 1):

S3 files are upload to at least 3 availability zones in the same region, and amazon provides load balancing automatically, but if you need lower latency, you will probably need [CloudFront](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Introduction.html) , that works like a CDN distributing your file to other regions, in order to make it available in a place more near the user, but this will increase your running costs considerably.